Why doesn't the compiler align data to the nearest 2^N bytes<= the cache line?
My limited understanding of memory alignment in C++ is that structures are typically aligned to the strictest alignment requirement of any member. This means that size of a struct is always a multiple of its largest member.
struct Foo {
  char a; // +3 bytes padding
  long b;
  char c; // +3 bytes padding
}; // 12 bytes total

Say we have an array of 6 of theses structs, for a total of 72 bytes.
When (most) hardware reads from cache, it reads 64 bytes at a time. This array flows over the cache line, meaning the hardware needs to read the next 64 bytes if you request the last element.
In this case, wouldn't it be more effective to pad structs to the nearest power of 2 less than 64? This would eliminate that problem. My guess is that the extra memory consumption outweighs the potential benefit, especially the jump from 32 to 64 bytes, but how do you even come to a conclusion like that?

"In this case, wouldn't it be more effective to pad structs to the nearest power of 2 less than 64?" -- Are you saying it would be effective to illegally align a struct member? How do you drop four padding bytes from this structure while maintaining the (assumed) alignment requirement for long?

This would eliminate that problem. Which problem, can you elaborate it? You mentioned the hardware needs to read the next 64 bytes if you request the last element, why is this a problem?

Or were you thinking thatFoo should be expanded to 16 bytes (not reduced to 8)? In which case the problem you seek to address is needing a second cache line when reading the first six elements of the array, and your "solution" is to require a second cache line when reading just the first five?

"if you request the last element" -- Are you thinking about requesting just the last element, not the entire array? If you're going that route, you might as well assume that the request is for just the b field in the last element. It's a matter of consistency -- either read the entire data structure (your array of Foo) or read just one primitive type (long, char, etc.) within the data structure. Anything else is an arbitrary combination of "all" and "one" at different logical levels, and I think it's up to you to establish that your preferred combination is what should be looked at.

Cache line sizes vary.  Writing portable C++ code to account for Intel/AMD 64 byte, versus ARM M2 128 byte, versus MIPS and RISC-V 32 byte, versus s390x 256 byte cache lines is tricky.  If profiling shows that cache line is a performance issue for a given platform, the structure can be micro-optimized by hand to have the desired platform-specific alignment traits.

@JaMit My wording was bad and my question wasn't clear. Whether you are loading one or all of the elements doesn't matter. Assuming that each struct corresponds to a single load according to the ISA, six 12-byte structs will result in six loads and seven accesses, because at least one of the loads will straddle over the cache line. six 16-byte structs will result in six loads and six accesses.

@EmreTekmen "My wording was bad and my question wasn't clear." -- Yes, that is a quick summary of my comments. It's good that you recognize it. Your next step should be to [edit] your question to make the wording better and the question clear.

Quite a bit of hardware requires that a load from memory of a particular size be aligned to a multiple of that size. This is common enough it's often called "natural alignment". Even hardware that does support non-natural alignment often imposes fairly substantial penalties for it.
So, in your struct if b is at an odd address, the hardware won't support a 32-bit (or larger) load from that address. Even on that hardware, you could make it work, but the code would get ugly--to get that 32 bits, you'd issue a 64-bit load from the previous 64-bit aligned address, then shift and mask to isolate the 32 bits you cared about.
If you have a 64-bit item at an odd address, it gets even uglier--issue two loads from 64-bit aligned addresses, then shift and make both, and OR the makes results together.
There are situations where you can gain more from storing more data in the cache than you lose from doing shifting/masking to get to the right data. But you'd generally only do such a thing in response to profiling showing that it was beneficial, not just the compiler deciding to do that on its own.
